# Enabling users to download current data on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page that lists records based on the parameters given in the search filter. I need to give a download link, wherein the current records on the page are written to a file and given as a link to be downloaded.

So to put it simple, how do I give the latest records found based on the search parameters as a download link ?

P.S : I'm using the send_file method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could link to the download action using a custom :format merged with the query params. Something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Download", posts_path(params.except("action", "controller").merge(:format => "csv")) %>
```

Not the cleanest example but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSV writer to generate the required file and give a download link to the file for users.

Thanks, Anubhaw

Comment: Which is exactly what i'm using. Thing is , I need to export the result of the latest GET request as a CSV, when asked to.